# Use of implicit parameter in spark

Tags: apache-spark, implicit-conversion

Below code is used to find the average of values.I am not sure why implicit num: Numeric[T] parameter used in average function.

Code:

```
val data = List(("32540b03",-0.00699), ("a93dec11",0.00624),
                ("32cc6532",0.02337) , ("32540b03",0.256023),
                ("32cc6532",-0.03591),("32cc6532",-0.03591))    

val rdd = sc.parallelize(data.toSeq).groupByKey().sortByKey()    

def average[T]( ts: Iterable[T] )**( implicit num: Numeric[T] )** = {    
   num.toDouble( ts.sum ) / ts.size    
}

val avgs = rdd.map(x => (x._1, average(x._2)))
```

Please help to know the reason for using ( implicit num: Numeric[T]) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Scala does not have a super class for numeric types. This means you can't limit T <: Number for the average to make sense (you can't really do an average of generic objects). By adding implicit you make sure it has the toDouble method which converts to double.

You could pass that conversion function always but that would mean an additional parameter so instead numeric is used. If you would do something like average(List("bla")) you would get a complaint that it can't find a num.

See also https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#otherbounds